# Date in free format into db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model with `:birth_date` of type `date`.

I've tried to put a string like `3 janvier 1968` (French language) into that field and somehow in database I saw that PostgreSQL or someone else converted it into a date!

I also tried some other dates like `3 février 1968` or like `3 fevrier 1968` which didn't work and turned out to be `NULL` in db.

I can't find information about this feature anywhere. How does this work?

Answer (score 2):

Rails knows that attribute is a `Date` from the database definition, so it converts the string you give it to a `Date`. If you create a new instance of your model in the Rails console and assign to `birth_date`, you can show that it's already a Date even before you save it to the database:

```
m = Model.new # Use your model name
m.birth_date = "3 février 1968"
m.birth_date.class
```

The console should tell you that `m.birth_date` is a `Date`.

So the conversion to `Date` is done before you save the model to the database. Rails defines a `String::to_date` method that calls the Ruby `::Date.parse` method, which converts various human-readable date strings into a `Date` (https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse). In the Rails source, you'll see that whatever you assign to a `Date` attribute is converted to a `Date` with the `to_date` method. So when you assign a `String`, it happens via `String::to_date` which calls `Date.parse`.

As you mentioned in your comment, `Date.parse` seems to take a fairly loose approach to the months when they're spelled out. I tried a variety of English, French, and Spanish months in `Date.parse`, and as long as the first three letters of the non-English month are the same as the English month, `Date.parse` will convert them. But if the first three letters are different, then `Date.parse` throws an error.

Comment: I thought about locale too, but I have `en_US.UTF-8` locale. This is strange

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. Is your question, "Why does Rails convert a string to a date", or is it, "Why does Rails convert a French date to a date, when my locale is English," or both?

Comment: Both. I also was thinking about this, and I have an idea. `janvier` starts with `jan` as in English. `février` doesn't start with `feb`. Maybe Rails automatically tries to convert string to date as if it was a date in some English format.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a column in the database as type 'date', it will only save as a date.  Rails does it's best to convert a string into a recognized date if possible.  You should always pass the 'birth_date' data as a date (i.e. use a date_field).  Otherwise, if you REALLY want to store it as a string, the birth_date column must be of type string in the database